# update user information in firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am using angularFire in its latest version **2.0.1**, but I see information on how to update information as "displayName" try to obtain user information with `firebase.User()` but I get error "getApi" I am misguided quisas how to update the information a user created earlier

Comment: which firebase version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using the latest version sdk 3.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.
You can do the following:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: vm.form.username
}).then(function(response) {
  //Success
}, function(error) {
  //Error
  console.log(error);
});
```