# How do I set the displayName of Firebase user using angular 4?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have been trying to get the value of the **displayName** for my users that sign up using Email and password, It always gives me `null`.

This is my **AuthService**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authState: any = null;

 user$: Observable<firebase.User>;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private userService: UserService) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState;
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
      this.authState = auth;
    });

  }
  
  signUp(email, password) {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,      password)
      .then((user) => {
        this.authState = user;
    })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  
   private updateUserData(): void {

    const path = `users/${this.currentUserId}`; // Endpoint on firebase
    const data = {
      email: this.authState.email,
      name: this.authState.displayName
    };

    this.db.object(path).update(data)
      .catch(error => console.log(error));

  }
```

**this is my signup.ts**

```js
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
              private user: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSignup(form: NgForm) {
     const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      user.updateProfile({
      displayName: form.value.username,
      photoURL: 'https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg'
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        const displayName = user.displayName;
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    const name = form.value.username;
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.auth.signUp(email, password);
```

I don't know how I can use the name gotten from the `signUp` form and make it to the `displayName` for a **firebase.user**

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619609/update-user-information-in-firebase

Comment: please refrain from using the **angularjs** tag if your question is about **angular**

Comment: I'm still getting error 'Cannot read property 'updateProfile' of null
    at SignupComponent'